# timing a gui input window in powershell

Tags: powershell, user-interface, time

I am trying to put a time limit for an input box before which it closes.

I have used the if command and end-date
such that:

```
$endDate = (Get-Date).AddSeconds(10)
while ((Get-Date) -lt $endDate) { 


[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Data Entry Form"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"



$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
{$Choice = $objTextBox.SelectedItem.ToString(); $objForm.Close()}})




$objForm.Topmost = $True

if ((Get-Date) -ge $Fate) { $objForm.Invoke( }


$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
 [void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
}

if ((Get-Date) -ge $endDate) { #whatever Function Here}
```

it seems that the input box stops all the actions of the script. I have tried to time the second function (the one starting with if) inside the same function without using the while loop but it didn't work.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This code looks broken in multiple ways, and your question is hard to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the input box stops actions of the script, it may not block event subscriptions from running. If that's the case, you could use the `System.Timers.Timer` class to register a timeout.

If you create the following event registration just before you invoke the input box, it may allow you to close the input box.

```
$Timer = New-Object -TypeName System.Timers.Timer;
$Timer.Interval = 30000; # Timeout in milliseconds (30 seconds)

$Action = {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10; # Create a delay for the action
    $objForm.Close(); # This line *should* close the Form object
    $Timer.Enabled = $false; # Stop the timer from executing
    Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier Timer | Unregister-Event; # Unregister the event handler
    };

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Timer -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier Timer -Action $Action;
$Timer.Enabled = $true;
```

Comment: the code works well, thank you. but I don't want $Action to start at time 0. I couldn't manage to fix it. In addition, I want to remove the objectevent after the execution of the code.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a delay for the action (virtually causing a 40 second instead of 30 second delay), and also added a line that unregisters the event subscription.